# Django REST API login from different auth table

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I need to login, logout a user with Django REST. Its an API created to be called from different apps, so I need to mantain a session. My problem is that I found a lot of solutions but I dont know witch work best with my case. I have Model named User, and I want to register, login and logout with him, with a email and password. My first question is, does work for me login with Django auth methods? Its like for every user I create with my API in table User , I need to create another instance on django auth to login, logout? And it will work to be able to do API calls? Im a bit lost. If you know some reference that I can check that work perfectly with my case, please send it to me.

Comment: I used django-knox (token authentication) for login/logout. If you don't need user to login from multiple devices, you can use django's token authentication.

Comment: You can see the [custom authentication](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/) in django docs